# Can I make a table cell have a different background color if the value =< a particular number with jquery or PHP?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML table with a lot of numbers.

Is it possible to have a table cell change background color if the value inside that cell (or column) equals or is less than a particular number?

For example:  if cell =< "3000", background-color=#FF0000

Is there a way to make this work in reality?

Erik

Comment: You are going to need more tags. Do you want to do this with client side script or server side script? What technology are you using. Right now the only way to answer your question is "Yes. You can do that."

Comment: Your cell value can changes after page loading or value always is static during all page life? In other words: you need to dinamically change background of cell or background can be applied only once?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how to do it with JS/Jquery

```
$("#Yourtable td").each( function() {
     var thisCell = $(this);
     var cellValue = parseInt(thisCell.text());

     if (!isNaN(cellValue) && (cellValue <=3000)) {
         thisCell.css("background-color","#FF0000");
      }
  }
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
var table = document.getElementById("tableId");
var row = table.rows[rowIndex];
var cell = row.cells[cellIndex];

var cellValue = Number(cell.innerHTML);

if (cellValue > 3000)
  cell.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is easy to do this sort of thing.

For example, with jQuery, something like this:

```
$('table.mytable td').each(function() {
  if (this.textContent <= 3000) {
    $(this).css('background', '#FF0000');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use code like this:

```
$(".colorMe td").each(function() {
    var val = parseInt(this.innerHTML, 10);
    if (val < 3000) {
        this.style.backgroundColor = "#F00000";
    }
});
```

See a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/GAwrB/.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example
//CSS

```
.lowerthan100{
 background-color:red;
 color:white;   
}
.higherthan100{
 background-color:white;   
 color:red;
}
```

//JAVASCRIPT

```
$('#mytable td').each(function() {
    if(parseInt($(this).html())>100){
    $(this).addClass("higherthan100");
    }else if (parseInt($(this).html())<100){
    $(this).addClass("lowerthan100");
    }    
 });
```

//HTML

```
<table border="1px" id="mytable">
    <tr><td>99</td><td>101</td></tr>
    <tr><td>200</td><td>50</td></tr>
</table>
```

You can populate more `class` in CSS and `else if` statements, if you need more conditions.

Here is the live example http://jsfiddle.net/kayadiker/DL6U2/2/