# change between 3 different background color based on cell value

Tags: javascript, css, joomla

I have a booking page on my Joomla! 2.5 website where visitors can sign up for events; these events have 3 different statuses :
less than 20: preliminary (open for registrants)
more than 20: confirmed (still open for registrants)
60: full (closed for registrants)

I'm hoping to use javascript (or just css if possible) to change the background-color of a table cell based on the value pulled from the registrants-table. I have found several similar questions asked here, but so far only with two values: like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425719/can-i-make-a-table-cell-have-a-different-background-color-if-the-value-a-part).

I have cloned latest live example at jsfiddle dot net and tried to make it work, but have messed it up so that it does not work... I'm not even sure what the best way to incorporate it into the component in question once it does work ('',) Hoping there are someone that can point me in the right direction?

unable to post link /DaBouncer/DL6U2/185/]

Comment: If you're already using PHP, it would be by far more efficient to add a class to the elements in question on the server side than to have JavaScript do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correct you want the following:

HTML:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>12</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table td {
    padding: 5px 30px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
var cell = $('td');

cell.each(function() {
var cell_value = $(this).html();
if ((cell_value >= 0) && (cell_value <=2)) {
    $(this).css({'background' : '#FF0000'});   
} else if ((cell_value >= 3) && (cell_value <=7)) {
    $(this).css({'background' : '#0066CC'});
} else if (cell_value >= 8) {
    $(this).css({'background' : '#00CC66'});
}
});
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/4Yp95/

## EDIT

Try creating a script.js file (in a folder called 'js') with the jquery code in it and load it after jquery, right before the closing  tab, in 'index.php' file:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

Maybe it works

Comment: That looks good, thanks.
However I guess it needs to be hardcoded with an ID so that is does not render bg-color in all table cells containing numbers on this particular page? Something like id="bg_status" for the table in question? http://jsfiddle.net/DaBouncer/SxQu6/1/

Comment: I would suggest class="bg_status" instead of id, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/SxQu6/2/.

Comment: Thanks again Kapantzak. It does exactly what I wanted, but unfortunately I have not been able to make it work in Joomla! 2.5.9. I have tried loading jQuery in the templates head, tried via plugin Custom JavaScript and MetaMod and jQuery Easy, but still no luck.

Comment: I've tried inside public_html/components/com_eventbooking/views/event/tmpl/default.php and also inside head of public_html/templates/jsn_pixel_pro/index.php. I don't think public_html/index.php is supposed to be altered in Joomla. By your edited answer, do you mean http://jsfiddle.net/SxQu6/2/ ? If so, I tried using that code.

Comment: Ahh, sorry I did not see the edit above, will look into it ('',)

Comment: Finally got it working, thanks for your input! Only one thing had to be sorted as it added bg-color to all my td's containing numbers, so I moved the class="bg_status" to the td and changed the first line of the script to var cell = $('td.bg_status');

Comment: I'm glad to hear that you solved your problem! If you found my answer helpfull, please click the accept button! Thanks!