# change between 3 different background color based on cell value but only if another call value is different than

Tags: javascript, php, css

I was helped along a while back with some code for changing background color in a table cell; the final solution works very well:
[change between 3 different background color based on cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16135255/change-between-3-different-background-color-based-on-cell-value)

Now I'd like to add another condition for this, please take a look here to see what I mean: unable to post link: jsfiddle dot net/Bouncer/LeyqceLe/4/

Is this at all possible without loosing the current function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is my friend: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kjk4zhfz/1/)

It gets the value of avai :

```
var diff = $('td.avai').html();
```

then checks if the value of the `avai` cell is other than 20, and skips the cell colouring:

```
if(diff != 20) {    ...    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understand right this is what you want?

```js
// JavaScript Document
var cell = $('td.bg_status');
// Get the td value
var avai_value = $('.avai').text();

cell.each(function() {

    var cell_value = $(this).html();
    // continue if td value is not 20
    if(avai_value!=20){
        if ((cell_value >= 0) && (cell_value <=19)) {
            $(this).css({'background' : '#FF9900'});   
        } else if ((cell_value >= 20) && (cell_value <=39)) {
            $(this).css({'background' : '#99cc00'});
        } else if (cell_value >= 40) {
            $(this).css({'background' : '#99ccff'});
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: 3 years later and I am still using this on my Joomla! site; code placed in the template (custom code), works great!

To add some flexibility in how I use this script it would be great if another condition can be used to switch between two sets of numeric values: script first checks if <td class="text"> contains "ying"; then use current values (14, 15, 49 and 50) and if it contains "yang" we instead use (7, 8, 59 and 60).

Anyone that have an idea if this can be done?

Current code here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/jo59bn67/)

Rgds,

Bouncer

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to mention earlier that my site is running Joomla! 3. I was just informed that Joomla doesn't allow to use $ signs for a while for jQuery codes. Also the line with avai_value caused an error and had to be rewritten like so:

```
// JavaScript Document
if(jQuery('td.avai').length){
    var cell = jQuery('td.bg_status');
    var diff = jQuery('td.avai').html();
    cell.each(function() {
        var cell_value = jQuery(this).html();
        if(diff != 20) {    
            if ((cell_value >= 0) && (cell_value <=19)) {
                jQuery(this).css({'background' : '#FF9900'});   
            } else if ((cell_value >= 20) && (cell_value <=39)) {
                jQuery(this).css({'background' : '#99cc00'});
            } else if (cell_value >= 40) {
                jQuery(this).css({'background' : '#99ccff'});
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I am writing custom modules for Joomla 3.8.6 and my jquery code uses `$(selector)`.  The trouble only comes when you have a clash of scripts using the `$`.