# set variable to use in jquery

Tags: jquery, joomla, background-color

3 years later and I am still using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29537116/change-between-3-different-background-color-based-on-cell-value-but-only-if-anot) on my Joomla! site running Event Booking component; code is now placed in the template (custom code), works great!

Script illustrates - with background colors in a td - if there are

1) too few (orange)
2) just enough (green), or
3) too many (blue) attendants to my events.

Now there is a second venue with different levels and two types of events; hoping to add a function to include that in the script.

[This illustrates best what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgGx5.png) (image)

Current I'm using [this code](https://jsfiddle.net/Bouncer/jo59bn67/) jsfiddle

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
if(jQuery('td.avai').length){
    var cell = jQuery('td.bg_status');
    var diff = jQuery('td.avai').html();
    cell.each(function() {
        var cell_value = jQuery(this).html();
        if(diff != 12) {    
            if ((cell_value >= 0) && (cell_value <=11)) {
                jQuery(this).css({'background' : '#FF9900'});   
            } else if ((cell_value >= 12) && (cell_value <=49)) {
                jQuery(this).css({'background' : '#99cc00'});
            } else if (cell_value >= 50) {
                jQuery(this).css({'background' : '#99ccff'});
            }
        }
    });
}
});
```

Rgds,

Bouncer

Comment: I don't see anything Joomla-specific in your posted code, but if you specifically require Joomla support you might like to post @ https://joomla.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
if(jQuery('td.avai').length){
    var cell = jQuery('td.bg_status');
    var diff = jQuery('td.avai').html();
    cell.each(function() {
        var cell_value = jQuery(this).html();
      var textValue= jQuery('td.text').html().replace(/\s/g,'');
      var array1;
      if (textValue==='ying')
      {     
        array1=[14,15,49,50];

      }
      else if (textValue==='yang')
      {
        array1=[7,8,59,60];

      }

        if(diff != array1[1]) {    
            if ((cell_value >= 0) && (cell_value <=array1[0])) {
                jQuery(this).css({'background' : '#FF9900'});   
            } else if ((cell_value >= array1[1]) && (cell_value <=array1[2])) {
                jQuery(this).css({'background' : '#99cc00'});
            } else if (cell_value >= array1[3]) {
                jQuery(this).css({'background' : '#99ccff'});
            }
        }
    });
}
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much MMSA. After some more testing it seems the function for td.avai is no longer working in Joomla.
Some more info might be useful: td.avai is representing available slots for events; if one events capacity is defined (ex. 40) bg_color is rendered in td.bg_status. For events that have unlimited capacity td.avai is empty = td.bg_status should not have any bg_color.

Please ignore my previous comment; I decided to skip the sentences and use single words.

Comment: Strange but the jsfiddle behaves differently than Joomla; if I delete
  <td class="avai"> 20 </td> simulating an unlimited capacity event (as explained above) it does not render bg_color, but in Joomla it does even if that td is missing...

Comment: @MMSA "Try This" answers are low-value on StackOverflow because they do very little to educate the OP and future researchers.  When you do not properly educate those who ask questions, you perpetuate a dependency loop, where developers rely on StackOverflow to solve all of their issues rather than toil to self-solve.  Please improve your answer to explain how your solution works and why it is advisable.

Answer (score 0):

first, the current $ in your function argument serves no purpose whatsoever.
What you need, is to use an IIFE taking 'jQuery' as an argument, so that you can isolate your code and use $ safely inside.

Then, your use of 'limits' is a bit odd, i am not sure if you know the difference between strictly and not strictly superior/inferior.

anyway, a version of the code that works would be https://jsfiddle.net/859mfkvL/17/

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
    if ($('td.avai').length) {
      var cell = $('td.bg_status');
      var diff = $('td.avai').html();
      var txt = $('td.text').html();
      var limits;

      if (txt.indexOf('yang') === -1) {
        limits = [14, 15, 49, 50];
      } else {
        limits = [7, 8, 59, 60];
      }

      cell.each(function() {
          var cell_value = $(this).html();
          if(diff != 15) {    
              if ((cell_value >= 0) && (cell_value <= limits[0])) {
                  $(this).css({'background' : '#FF9900'});   
              } else if ((cell_value >= limits[1]) && (cell_value <=limits[2])) {
                  $(this).css({'background' : '#99cc00'});
              } else if (cell_value >= limits[3]) {
                  $(this).css({'background' : '#99ccff'});
              }
          }
      });
        }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thank you for your input @JulienV I'll do some testing over the next few days.

Comment: I have forked your suggestion and added a more extensive comment: I hope this explanation is better. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/Bouncer/7zt4qfs2/)

Comment: well, your comment on fiddle is another level of requirements... I am not familiar with event booking generated output, but i am wondering if you wouldn't be better tuning the code in a template override rather that with js. e.g implement some php function that will directly ouput the wanted class depending on the 'event' properties.

Comment: English is not my first language so perhaps my explanation is not the best; I don't think there are any major changes except I realized the background on drop-in event should be green no matter what.

Comment: to check if the capacity is not a number, just use isNaN()

Comment: I'm not a coder myself, but until you mentioned isNaN() I was thinking along these lines: could it work to add class="capacity" to a td, then | var capacity = $('td.capacity').html(); | and perhaps use jQuery.isNumeric() | and then add to this line | if(diff != 12) { | something like | if((diff != 12) && (capacity "is not numeric")) {

Comment: sure, there is more than 1 possible answer.