# Can I make a number in a table cell have a different color based on its value using JavaScript/AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a HTML page with a table that is created using Angular `ng-repeat` and a controller that fetches JSON data.

Here is the simplified version of my table:

```
product  price
-------  -----
ABC      $1.33
EDF      $2.00
```

And here is the angularJS code inside my HTML page:

```
<table class="table" ng-controller="someCtrl">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="p in products">
            <td>{{p.productName}}</td>
            <td>{{p.price}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Is it possible to change the text color of p.price based on its value? for example, I would like to modify the price value with the color red `if p.price > 1.5`

I have tried the following answer, but it only works when I hard-coded the number instead of dynamic generating number using `ng-repeat`:
[Can I make a table cell have a different background color if the value =< a particular number with jquery or PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425719/can-i-make-a-table-cell-have-a-different-background-color-if-the-value-a-part)

Comment: How did you try that linked answer? Show us more code. (It can be done, yes.)

Comment: Hi i think you can find an answer from this link...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18745001/how-will-i-change-the-color-of-a-font-based-on-a-value-using-angularjs-directive

Comment: @phpfresher thanks! I actually checked the answer but did not quite get it the first time. but it is what I need for sure! thanks !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of jQuery, you can achieve this by `ng-class`.

```
<td><span ng-class="p.price > 1.5 ? 'price-red' : ''">{{p.price}}</span></td>
```

**CSS**

```
.price-red {
    // apply your code like 
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: nice and simple! Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

A cleaner way to do it would be using the ng-class directive in angularjs. For the  tag, you can optionally give a css class depending on the value of an expression as follows:

```
<td ng-class="{ 'css-cls-for-color1' : p.price > 3000, 'css-cls-for-color2' : p.price <= 3000}"> </td>
```

Comment: what is the meaning of adding same answer again.. as  @Arulkumar did the same

Comment: the approaches are different. And anyways, when i was constructing my answer, there was no answer by Arulkumar , OK @pankajparkar?

Comment: I don't say that @Arulkumar is also evaluating expression inside `ng-class`